# android - Cannot copy database from assets folder : API < 24

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, kotlin

Hi have an issue whereby I am unable to copy my database (called xyz) from my assets folder to the /data/data/com.example.app1beta/databases/xyz folder on any api below 24. Running the same code on api 24 and above I have no issues. The database file xyz.db is in the assets/databases folder. The error I get is the following:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.app1beta/databases/xyz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Any help would be much appreciated! Thx!

```
    val DATABASE_NAME = "xyz"

    class SQL_LITE_DB(val context: Context): SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,1) {

        private val preferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "${context.packageName}.database_versions",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )

        private fun installDatabaseFromAssets() {
            val inputStream = context.assets.open("$ASSETS_PATH/$DATABASE_NAME.db")
            try {
                val outputFile = File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).path)
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)

                inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
                inputStream.close()
                outputStream.flush()
                outputStream.close()
            } catch (exception: Throwable) {
                throw RuntimeException("The $DATABASE_NAME database couldn't be installed.", exception)
            }
        }

            companion object {
            const val ASSETS_PATH = "databases"
        }
```

Comment: You are not creating the directory. The directory for databases is not automatically created just by calling `getDatabasePath()`. You need to create it yourself, using `mkdirs()`.

Comment: I see, though I fail to understand why I don't have this issue with api 24 and up?

Comment: Perhaps newer versions of Android do automatically create it. It never used to be that way, but things change in Android. It is safest to always call `mkdirs()`, because `mkdirs()` will simply do nothing if the desired directory already exists.

Comment: Agreed! Thanks very much for the assistance in this matter. I hope this fix helps others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is likely that the **databases** directoryr does not exist (it will not for a newly installed App).

Thus you need to create the directory if it doesn't exist. e.g. :-

```
private fun installDatabaseFromAssets() {
    val inputStream = context.assets.open("$ASSETS_PATH/$DATABASE_NAME.db")
    val dbFile = File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString())
    if (!dbFile.exists()) {
        if (!dbFile.parentFile.exists()) {
            dbFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
        }
    }
    try {
        //val outputFile = File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).path)
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(dbFile)

        inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
        inputStream.close()
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
    } catch (exception: Throwable) {
        throw RuntimeException("The $DATABASE_NAME database couldn't be installed.", exception)
    }
}
```